# Why so much difference in memory used per process in apache2 between two different systems?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache2, ram

I have a pair of Ubuntu dedicated servers...

Server1:

```
Ubuntu 16.04.7 (64 bits)
16GB RAM
8 Xeon CPU
Apache 2.4.18
MPM mode: prefork
```

Server2:

```
Ubuntu server 20.04.2 (64 bits)
32GB RAM
8 Xeon CPU
2.4.41
MPM mode: event
```

On Server1, each apache2 process uses between 7MB and 18MB of RAM ...

```
ps axo 'user rss cmd' | grep apache | grep -v "\(root\|grep\|tomcat\)"
www-data 18232 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 11700 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 11276 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 10792 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 11216 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 11600 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 10336 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 11356 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 11348 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 10980 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 11316 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  6808 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

On Server2, each apache2 process uses between 120MB and 130MB of RAM ...

```
ps axo 'user rss cmd' | grep apache | grep -v "\(root\|grep\|tomcat\)"
www-data 120436 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 119784 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 128720 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 130208 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

Why so much difference in memory used?

After read a few documentation and *googleing*, I thought about loaded modules, but there are not a lot of difference between each server...

Server1

```
# apache2 -M                 
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 actions_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 auth_digest_module (shared)
 auth_openidc_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 bw_module (shared)
 cgi_module (shared)
 dav_module (shared)
 dav_fs_module (shared)
 dav_lock_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 expires_module (shared)
 fcgid_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 include_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_balancer_module (shared)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 slotmem_shm_module (shared)
 socache_shmcb_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 suexec_module (shared)
 userdir_module (shared)
```

Server2

```
# apache2 -M
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 aclr_module (shared)
 actions_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 auth_digest_module (shared)
 auth_openidc_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 cgid_module (shared)
 dav_module (shared)
 dav_fs_module (shared)
 dav_lock_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 fcgid_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 include_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_event_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_balancer_module (shared)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 remoteip_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 security2_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 slotmem_shm_module (shared)
 socache_shmcb_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 suexec_module (shared)
 unique_id_module (shared)
 userdir_module (shared)
```

I already changed MPM mode from Event to Prefork on Server2, with the same results.

What else can I check to understand this difference?

Comment: Maybe the threading of the event MPM? Have you tried configuring Server2 to use MPM Prefork like Server1?

Comment: Thank's for answer @studersi and yes, as I already said, I already changed MPM mode from Event to Prefork on Server2, with the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the module security2.

With the module enabled (120-160MB per process) ...

```
# ps axo 'user rss cmd' | grep apache | grep -v "\(root\|grep\|tomcat\)"
www-data 121232 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 120596 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 156816 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 162668 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

With the module disabled (9-15MB per process) ...

```
# a2dismod security2
Module security2 disabled.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  systemctl restart apache2
# systemctl restart apache2
# ps axo 'user rss cmd' | grep apache | grep -v "\(root\|grep\|tomcat\)"
www-data 10340 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9764 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 14164 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 14220 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

You can follow an email conversation here: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-users/202105.mbox/%3CCAD41RFYjd3XcAEqopgVWKQUnsiv9NCHRLGTM0tEOD4Kg8%2B_2hA%40mail.gmail.com%3E

Comment: Hi there (I'm Dino from apache users). You can close your own answer as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: Done! Thank's @dAm2K